# Do I need to split the data for isolation forest?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I have a database that consists of 10049972 rows x 19 columns. I was using Isolation Forest to detect outliers, then created an extra column that has outliers set as -1, I dropped all rows containing outliers as -1 then removed the column.

My question is: Do I need to do train, test and validate for isolation forest to work? Also can someone please confirm if my code is valid?

Here is my code.

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest


df = pd.read_csv('D:\\Project\\database\\4-Final\\Final After.csv',low_memory=True)


iForest = IsolationForest(n_estimators=100,  contamination=0.1 , random_state=42, max_samples=200)


iForest.fit(df.values.reshape(-1,1))

pred = iForest.predict(df.values.reshape(-1,1))

pred=df['anomaly']

df=df.drop(df['anomaly'==-1],inplace=True)

df.to_csv('D:\\Project\\database\\4-Final\\IF TEST.csv', index=False)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is do I need to do test train and validate for isolation forest to work?

**You want to detect outliers in just this batch file, right?** **In this case, your solution may be ok,** **but in most cases, you must split.**

But please, try to understand when would you need to do the split.
To explain this, let's enter into a real case scenario.

Let's suppose you are trying to predict the anomalous behaviour of different engines. You create a model using the data available in your database until "today", and start predicting incoming data. It may be possible that the predicted data is not equal to the data used to train, right? Then, how can you simulate this situation when you are configuring your model? Using train-test-validate and evaluating with the right metrics.

Edit: Let me add an example. I'll try to make it super simple.

If your engine *data base* data is:

```
+----+-------------+--------------+
| id | engine_type | engine_value |
+----+-------------+--------------+
|  1 |           0 | 0.25         |
|  2 |           0 | 0.40         |
|  3 |           1 | 0.16         |
|  4 |           1 | 0.30         |
|  5 |           0 | 5.3          | <- anomaly
|  6 |           1 | 14.4         | <- anomaly
|  7 |           0 | 16.30        | <- anomaly
+----+-------------+--------------+
```

And use it all to train the model, the model will use the three anomalous values to train, right? The algorithm will create the forest using these 3 anomalous values, so it can be easier for the model to predict them.

Now, what would happen with this *production* data:

```
+----+-------------+--------------+
| id | engine_type | engine_value |
+----+-------------+--------------+
|  8 |           1 | 3.25         | <- anomaly
|  9 |           1 | 4.40         | <- anomaly
| 10 |           0 | 2.16         |
+----+-------------+--------------+
```

You pass it to your model, and it says the points are not anomalous, but normal data, because it thinks your "threshold" is for values bigger than 5.

This "threshold" is product of the algorithm hyperparameters, maybe with other configuration, the model could have predicted the values as anomalous, but you are not testing the model **generalization**.

So how can you improve this configuration? Splitting the data that you have available at that moment. Instead of training with all the database data, you could have trained with only a part of it and use the other part to test, for example use this part as train data:

```
+----+-------------+--------------+
| id | engine_type | engine_value |
+----+-------------+--------------+
|  1 |           0 | 0.25         |
|  2 |           0 | 0.40         |
|  3 |           1 | 0.16         |
|  4 |           1 | 0.30         |
|  7 |           0 | 16.30        | <- anomaly
+----+-------------+--------------+
```

And this as test data:

```
+----+-------------+--------------+
| id | engine_type | engine_value |
+----+-------------+--------------+
|  5 |           0 | 5.3          | <- anomaly
|  6 |           1 | 14.4         | <- anomaly
+----+-------------+--------------+
```

And set a combination of hyperparameters that makes this algorithm predict the test data correctly. Does it ensure that in the future the predictions will be perfect? No, it does not, but it is not the same as just fitting the data without evaluating how well the model is generalizing.

> Also can someone please confirm if my code is valid?

Yes, but let me add a recommendation, changing this:

```
iForest.fit(df.values.reshape(-1,1))

pred = iForest.predict(df.values.reshape(-1,1))

pred=df['anomaly']
```

To this:

```
df['anomaly'] = iForest.fit_predict(df.values.reshape(-1,1))
```

Also, if you are using the new pandas version, use:

```
df['anomaly'] = iForest.fit_predict(df.to_numpy().reshape(-1,1))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that example! I'm sorry to ask but I do have a few more questions regarding your example to see if what I understood is correct because I'm new to all of this and a little confused.

1- In the first part of the example, since the normal data base that includes the anomalies  were used to train the database for the prediction of future values, these anomalies will present will lead to the inclusion of anomalies in the predicted data base since they have made the threshold higher?

Comment: 2- In the second example, since we split the data base that has only 1 anomaly, the threshold is much lower, and the test data base will be used to see if the isolation forest will detect the values in the test database as anomalies ?

3-  In my code , will the isolation forest be applied to each column individually since I have 19 columns ?

Comment: 4- In my case, I do need to test and train my data base correct? I'm just picking out the outliers, creating a column with -1 that indicates that this row has an outlier and I'm removing the entire column.

5- Lastly ,training and testing the database is just a way to make sure the the accuracy of the isolation forest is good?

I'm deeply sorry for all of these questions, thank you.

Comment: 1. The anomalies present in the train **could** lead the model to exclude the anomalies in the predicted data set. It's a could, because we do not really know.

Comment: 2. The threshold is not only defined by the data used to train, but it also uses the hyperparameters. If you set 10 trees instead of the default 100, the resulting threshold will be different. The objective is to know the optimal number of trees and then train the algorithm with all the data available and this optimal number of trees.

Comment: 3. https://towardsdatascience.com/outlier-detection-with-isolation-forest-3d190448d45e
4. If the objective is to use the model only for that file, then your solution is ok.
5. Is the way to make sure the accuracy will not decrease in the future!

Comment: Thank you very much , I got exactly the results I needed, I did remove the reshape part though.